# Submit Form With a Default Value After Certain Length of Time?

Tags: javascript, html

Okay, I am not to good with javascript and am just starting to learn it. All in all my form works but what I want to do is if a person does not answer any question on this quiz within 1 minute it will submit a value for unanswered. Lets call that value "e". So in my input I have value a,b,c,d and if they dont answer within a minute I want it to submit value "e". Right now the form submits but I have tried multiple ways to try to get it to submit with a value but it does not work

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
 <div id="quiz">
  <form method="post" id="test" name="test" action="<?php $user_answers->set_user_answers_action();?>">
    <p>
      <?php echo $test_questions->set_question(); ?>
    </p>
    <input type="hidden" id="answer" name="answer" value="<?php $user_answers->set_user_answers_field();?>">
    <input type="hidden" id="number_of_questions" name="number_of_questions" value="<?php echo $number_of_questions; ?>">
    <input type="radio" id="answerv" name="answerv" value="a" required>a&#41;
    <?php echo $test_questions->set_answer_a(); ?><br>
    <input type="radio" id="answerv" name="answerv" value="b" required>b&#41;
    <?php echo $test_questions->set_answer_b(); ?><br>
    <input type="radio" id="answerv" name="answerv" value="c" required>c&#41;
    <?php echo $test_questions->set_answer_c(); ?><br>
    <input type="radio" id="answerv" name="answerv" value="d" required>d&#41;
    <?php echo $test_questions->set_answer_d(); ?><br>
    <input type="submit" value="<?php $user_answers->set_user_answers_submit(); echo $user_answers->submit; ?>">
  </form>
</div>




<div style="font-weight: bold" id="quiz-time-left"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
  var max_time = 1;
  var c_seconds = 0;
  var total_seconds = 60 * max_time;
  max_time = parseInt(total_seconds / 60);
  c_seconds = parseInt(total_seconds % 60);
  document.getElementById("quiz-time-left").innerHTML = 'Time Left: ' + max_time + ' minutes ' + c_seconds + ' seconds';

  function init() {
    document.getElementById("quiz-time-left").innerHTML = 'Time Left: ' + max_time + ' minutes ' + c_seconds + ' seconds';
    setTimeout("CheckTime()", 999);
  }

  function CheckTime() {
    document.getElementById("quiz-time-left").innerHTML = 'Time Left: ' + max_time + ' minutes ' + c_seconds + ' seconds';
    if (total_seconds <= 0) {
      setTimeout('document.test.submit()', 1);
    } else {
      total_seconds = total_seconds - 1;
      max_time = parseInt(total_seconds / 60);
      c_seconds = parseInt(total_seconds % 60);
      setTimeout("CheckTime()", 999);
    }

  }
  init();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might add
`<input type="radio" name="answerv" value="e" style="display:none" checked>`
 somwhere in your form.

Comment: @JoeAlvini, happy to help!